# optimize android listview's getView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am wondering if there's a way I can pre-load a couple of views in Android ListView?

For example, by default, when a listview items scrolls out of the screen, it will become a convert view and will be re-decorated as the next view on screen. My problem is, each listview item is loading a pretty large size image from memory, and it will stuck scrolling if it begin load right before it is gonna show up.

I was wondering if there's a way I can specify the threshold of loading views, for example, to preload 3 views rather than 1?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit different approach for this:

First, remove your loading actions from adapter's `getView()`. This method should be as lite as possible. Load a first batch of images in background and pass it to adapter. (store in `List`, for example)

Second. Set `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` on your listView, override `onScroll()` and calculate the amount of views user has scrolled: `int count = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;`. If this int exceeds the number of images you loaded, start showing a progress bar and load your images in background thread, supplying them to your adapter (add to your `List`). Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after load is complete and you are done.

You can load as many items as you should.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer! One more question on this: by using this trick, do we need to generate a new view every time? how do I work around the convertview thing?

Comment: All views-related magic is performed by android under the hood. The only thing you can do is to implement a viewholder pattern to take advantage of view recycling and speed up view inflating by suppressing redundant `findViewById()` calls. There are plenty information about this pattern in the net. You're welcome.